# Websockets with Ratchet close immediately

Tags: php, html, websocket, ratchet

Using the directions on the [socketo.me](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world) site, I am trying to make websockets work using Ratchet for php. As per the instructions, I required Ratchet version 0.2.* in my composer.json file. I am using php 5.4.9-4ubuntu2 and Apache 2. For browsers I am using Firefox 21.0 and Chrome 26.0.1410.63. [This site](https://github.com/cboden/Ratchet) says Rachet supports Firefox 6-20 and Chrome 13-26, but the results are almost identical using Firefox 21 as in Chrome 26.

Here is my class that implements the MessageComponentInterface.

```
<?php
namespace WebsocketTest;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

require dirname (__DIR__).'/../../../../vendor/autoload.php';

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct ()
    {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen (ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach ($conn);
        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage (ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
        $numRecv = count ($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf ('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s'."\n", $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client)
        {
            if ($from !== $client)
            {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send ($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose (ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach ($conn);
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError (ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close ();
    }
}
```

Here is my shell script code.

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use WebsocketTest\Chat as Chat;

require_once __DIR__.'/Chat.php';

$server = IoServer::factory (new Chat (), 8080);
$server->run ();
```

Here is the output I get from the shell script.

```
New connection! (38)
Connection 38 sending message "GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: www.zf2.dev:8080
Origin: http://www.zf2.dev
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: YHbsxEgVhWTDJjaBJAGHdQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame

" to 1 other connection
New connection! (39)
Connection 39 sending message "GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.zf2.dev:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://www.zf2.dev
Sec-WebSocket-Key: EPpLFS3bXx/eC+WaoNDacA==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket

" to 2 other connections
Connection 37 has disconnected
Connection 38 has disconnected
```

Here is my javascript code. After the connection is created, I output it to the javascript console.

```
var conn = null;
function test_websockets ()
{
    conn = new WebSocket ('ws://www.zf2.dev:8080');
    console.log (conn);
    conn.onopen = function (e) { console.log ("Connection established!"); };
    conn.onmessage = function (e) { console.log (e.data); };
    conn.onclose = function (e) { console.log ('closed') };
//  conn.send ('sending message from the client');
}

function test_ws_message ()
{
    conn.send ('the test message');
}
```

This is the output I get in my javascript console in Chrome.

```
WebSocket {binaryType: "blob", extensions: "", protocol: "", onclose: null, onerror: null…}
 html5test.js:34
Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11 html5test.js:47
test_ws_message html5test.js:47
onclick
```

And this is the output I get from Firebug in Firefox.

```
WebSocket { url="ws://www.zf2.dev:8080", readyState=0, bufferedAmount=0, more...}
html5test.js (line 34)
InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
[Break On This Error]   

conn.send ('the test message');

html5test.js (line 47)
closed
html5test.js (line 38)
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://www.zf2.dev:8080/.


conn = new WebSocket ('ws://www.zf2.dev:8080');
```

Notice that Firefox shows that the connection closed immediately, and Chrome doesn't. However, Chrome never shows that the connection opened, so I don't think it is working on either browser. It looks like the server script thinks the connections were made, but neither browser ever shows me the "Connection established!" message which indicates that the onopen method was called. I was able to find one comment that suggested that incompatible versions of the websockets "handshake" might cause this to happen, but I never found any information about other version of Ratchet or what I would need to do to get compatible version running on client and server. I also found some comments that said that sometimes onopen doesn't get called at all, which I find hard to believe. Any ideas about what the problem might be or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like your clients are disconnecting when they receive a message from the server, which happens in onMessage(), so when the server receives a message from the client. Can you post the client code that sends the message to the server?

Comment: I actually hadn't gotten far enough to send any data to the server. But when I add the line `conn.send ('sending message from the client');` in the client side javascript, I get the following messages from the Chrome javascript console:
WebSocket {binaryType: "blob", extensions: "", protocol: "", onclose: null, onerror: null…}
Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11
closed

Comment: Well the server thinks it's getting a message, otherwise it would not fire onMessage(). Are you just calling test_websockets() in your html to produce the shell script output above?

Comment: Yes, I am calling test_websockets(). I have changed it so that the conn variable is global but that did not help, and I moved the call to conn.send() to a separate javascript function that I can call by clicking a div on my UI. The output above shows the message from OnMessage because I was originally trying to call send right after creating the connection. But I commented the call to send out to see if I could just create the connection first, but it closes every time.  Firefox is now telling me "InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable".

Comment: Can you update your question to include all your latest code? Following your code changes through comments is very confusing.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my code examples to reflect what I currently have, and the results I am getting on the server and the client.

Comment: Your browsers websockets should be compatible with Ratchet. I'm suspicious that this issue is an artifact of your testing. Are you establishing multiple connections from the same javascript console? If so, try using separate tabs or windows for each connection.

Comment: I think the client is trying to make a connection but the server never responds and the client ultimately times out. Because I can see the request get sent in Firebug but it never returns, and then the connection closes. I think you might be right that my client is not compatible with Ratchet. I just set up phpws and ran the demo server and it connected immediately and I was able to send a message just fine.

Answer (score 6):

If you follow Ratchet's documentation and RFC6455 properly then you will notice that when a websocket connection request is made, a specific response is to be sent to the client. Unless the response is received, the client will assume that the connection has not be made.

The problem on your case is that the `MessageComponentInterface` that is handling the connection is not responding with any socket response on connection. However, Ratchet bundles with a already implemented class called `WsServer` to which your Chat class's object can be passed and the desired operation can be achieved. However WsServer is not a `MessageComponentInterface`, but if you wrap it inside `HttpServer`, which is luckily also bundled with Ratchet, your problem will be solved.

So your new code will look like:

`$server = IoServer::factory (new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat ())), 8080);`

Ofcourse you will need to add WsServer and HttpServer in the namespace.

Answer (score 4):

use

```
$server = IoServer::factory (new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat())), 8080);
```

instead of

```
$server = IoServer::factory (new Chat (), 8080);
```